# How to display filter data in php in a proper manner

Tags: php

I want to display my data in a professional way that shorten the code length and look like professional.I didn't want to repeat the code.

Below I have paste my code. plz help me if any body has any best idea.

```
<table>
<?php if(!empty($labour) || !empty($machines) || !empty($materials) || !empty($contractors)){?>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>amount_paid</th>
        <th>date</th>
    </tr>
<?php }?>
<?php if(!empty($labour)){  

    $i=1; foreach($labour as $res):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['LabourCashcredit']['name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['LabourCashcredit']['amount_paid'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['LabourCashcredit']['date'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; 
}?>


<?php if(!empty($machines)){ 
    $i=1; foreach($machines as $res):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['MachinePayment']['first_name'].' '. $res['MachinePayment']['last_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['MachinePayment']['amount_paid'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['MachinePayment']['date'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; 
} ?>

<?php if(!empty($materials)){ 
    $i=1; foreach($materials as $res):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['MaterialPayment']['first_name'].' '. $res['MaterialPayment']['last_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['MaterialPayment']['paid_amount'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $res['MaterialPayment']['date'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php $i++; endforeach; 
} ?>
```

Comment: What propfessional way?? Would you please be more specific?

Comment: I bet the amount paid looks great left justified and presumably not formatted depending on the data type and can't remember reading too many financial documents with a heading of "amount_paid". But as above be more specific on what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat yourself here is some kind of approach for your particular case.

```
<table>
<?php if(!empty($labour) || !empty($machines) || !empty($materials) || !empty($contractors)):?>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>amount_paid</th>
        <th>date</th>
    </tr>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $items = array(); ?>

<?php
    if(!empty($labour))
      $items[] = array(
          'columns' => array(
              'name', // column 1
              'amount_paid', // column 2
              'date' // column 3
          ),
          'data' => $labour['LabourCashcredit']
      );

   if(!empty($machines))
      $items[] = array(
          'columns' => array(
              'first_name', // column 1
              'amount_paid', // column 2
              'date' // column 3
          ),
          'data' => $machines['MachinePayment']
      );

  // and so on ...
?>

<?php foreach($items as $key => $item_data): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $counter // think about some counter here ?></td>
        <?php foreach ($item_data['columns'] as $column): // looping through each column ?>
          <td><?php echo $item_data['data'][$column] // echoing column value ?></td>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>

<table>
```